# How to reorder included pdf-pages for bulk cutting ? [for paper saving]

Tags: pdfpages, sorting, paper-size, printing, pgfpages

## How to reorder included pdf-pages for bulk cutting ? [for paper saving]

#### Situation and Problem

I receive continuously updated lecture scripts as (A4) PDFs that I need to print.
The text area apparently fits onto A5 paper due to the large margins (that are usual with default LaTeX-documents).
In order to save some paper, I would like to print these A4 files as A5 but without resizing them (things become too small), but rather cutting edges.
Since I don't know how many pages this will be in the end, I can not use `signature`.

I know that this is bad from an aesthetical standpoint.

In the MWE below you can see, that I am trimming the included pages (try to use not `nup=1x2, landscape` but `frame, noautoscale`) from margins I found with `\layout` command.
However, I am unable to rearrange the order of the `nup=1x2` pages such that I could cut them in bulk and get ordered usual A5 sheets.
Later on I want to cut the pages and manually either glue- or hole-punch-bind them together.

#### Question

> How to reorder included `pdfpages` with `nup=1x2, landscape` to get bulk cut-able A5 pages?

Let me show the desired order with an adapted scheme from [here (please give Village credit)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60934/how-to-sort-the-order-of-pages-so-that-they-can-be-printed-in-a-folded-book).
It would be more practical for processing bigger volumes if the order was like this:

```
..[think of overlaying not folding here]..    [folding-view here]
(front of 1st paper)  (back of 1st paper)     (stacking order)
 ________ ________     ________ ________           /|======>>/|  ...==>>/|
|        |        |   |        |        |     1 ->/ |   3 ->/ |   h-1->/ |
|        |        |   |        |        |        /  |      /  |       /  |
|        |        |   |        |        |       / 2 |     / 4 |      / h |
|_____1__|___h+1__|   |__2_____|__h+2___|       |\  |     |\  |      |\  |
                                                | \ |     | \ |  ... | \ |  
(front of 2nd paper)  (back of 2nd paper)       |  \      |  \       |  \ 
 ________ ________     ________ ________        |   |     |   |      |   |
|        |        |   |        |        |       |h+1|     |h+3|      |n-1|
|        |        |   |        |        |        \  |      \  |       \  |
|        |        |   |        |        |         \ |<-h+2  \ |<-h+4   \ | <- n
|_____3__|___h+3__|   |__4_____|__h+4___|          \|======>>\|  ...==>>\|

...

(front of last paper) (back of last paper)
 ________ ________     ________ ________
|        |        |   |        |        |
|        |        |   |        |        |
|        |        |   |        |        |
|___h-1__|___n-1__|   |__h_____|__n_____|
```

... for `n` pages with `h := n/2`.

##### `MWE`

```tex
\documentclass[
    12pt, 
    twoside
]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}


% Border space as numbered in layout scheme ( https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376643/ )
% top = 2 - 4 + 5 + 6
\newlength{\distup}
\setlength{\distup}{\dimexpr\voffset+1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep\relax} % looks good with geometry a4paper but not without

% % left = 1+3
\newlength{\distleft}
\setlength{\distleft}{\dimexpr1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin\relax}
% \addtolength{\distleft}{20pt} % doesnt work due to twosided import

% % bottom = 11 + ? // = paperheight - oben - textheight
\newlength{\distdown}
\setlength{\distdown}{\dimexpr\paperheight-\distup-\textheight\relax}
% \addtolength{\distdown}{5pt} % we can cut a little more

% % right = 9 + 10 + ? // = paperwidth - link - textwidth
\newlength{\distright}
\setlength{\distright}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\distleft-\textwidth\relax}
% \addtolength{\distright}{20pt} % doesnt work due to twosided import
% %

\begin{document}
    \includepdf[
        pages=-,
        nup=1x2,
        landscape,
        clip,
        trim={{\distleft} {\distdown} {\distright} {\distup}},
        offset={-9pt 0pt}, % -9pt centers // works with twoside but not nup=1x2, landscape
        % noautoscale,
        frame
    ]{testfile.pdf}
    
\end{document}
```

I am using a given PDF but this should work for the MWE (though I noticed, that my margins don't seem to fit here?):

##### `testfile.tex`

```tex
\documentclass[
    12pt
]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

---

##### notes:

The first case "(might be easier to implement ?)" is solved in my own answer below, but not the remaining above.
I will keep this question up in order to focus on and accept answers for that part.

Comment: I just found [`pgfmorepages`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfmorepages) which should be able to cover the first layout.

Comment: Why don't you just use the Printing wizard (e.g. in Adobe Reader) and choose Multiple or Booklet?

Comment: @ivankokan Where would be the fun in that? Also I want to do this with LaTeX just *because* I don't like having to have a thousand and one programs for every little thing.

Comment: Certainly possible with pgfmorepages. The issue would be that the number of pages could vary from document to document so there's not a fixed layout that would do the trick. But a dynamic layout should be fine with a bit of LaTeX3 magic.  Might take a day or two, but I can think of a couple of ways to do this.

Comment: @AndrewStacey good to hear! What do you think is necessary for this to work? (Should I add some tags to the question?)

Answer (score 4):

There is `booklet.tex` macro in TeXlive (from olsak-misc package). Usage: create a document with two lines:

```
\def\document{filename}  % filename.pdf will be processed
\input booklet
```

and run `pdftex` with this two-line file (no LaTeX, no pdfLaTeX). The macro is documented in the book [TeX pro pragmatiky](https://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/tpp/tpp.pdf) (in Czech only). Or, you can use command line:

```
pdftex '\def\document{filename} \input booklet'
```

Comment: It does create a nice booklet. The order was like in the scheme in the question. From what I have seen, the printing result should be like the result in Andreas Matthias answer. I saw that I commented on missing some constraint about the ordering. But to be frank I can not wrap my head around the specific problem again. So currently I can not make the question more precise.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always calculate the correct value for `signature`. All you need
to know is the total number of pages of the pdf, which is accessible through
TeX-engine specific commands, like `\lastsavedimageresourcepages` from luaTeX.
Other engines name it differently.

In the following example I use some internal macros from pdfpages which are
independent of the TeX-engine, like `\AM@pagecount`, to get the total number of
pages. After a few short calculation the counter `mysig` contains the correct
value for `signature`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{mysig}
\newcommand\myincludepdf[2][]{%
  \def\AM@currentdocname{#2}%
  \AM@getpagecount
  \setcounter{mysig}{\AM@pagecount-\AM@pagecount/4*4}%
  \ifnum\c@mysig>0
    \setcounter{mysig}{\AM@pagecount/4*4+4}%
  \else
    \setcounter{mysig}{\AM@pagecount/4*4}%
  \fi
  \includepdf[#1,landscape, pages=-, signature=\c@mysig]{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\myincludepdf{dummy.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I don't think that it answers the question, as I was specifically asking for **non-`signature`** solutions, because *"I don't know how many pages [there] will be in the end, I can not use signature."*. Testing the code yielded a nice booklet for the part I had, but how would I incorporate future parts? (That is basically why I want it to be ordered as shown in the scheme.)

Comment: Do it in 2 steps: First, create a temporary pdf by concatenating all your pdfs. Second, use `\myincludepdf` as shown in the example.

Comment: The point of this question was, to have an option to print it along the way, in order to follow the current lectures. If that was no constraint, your solution was perfectly fine.

Comment: Of course, you can do it in one step: Instead of retrieving the number of pages of just **one** pdf, you sum up in a loop the number of pages over **all** pdfs. The calculation of the correct `signature` value is the same (but now with the total number of pages). And eventually you use `\includepdfmerge` instead of `\includepdf`.

Answer (score 0):

So I found [this solved question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279042/print-a6-book-on-a4-double-sided-in-correct-order/279057#279057) that answers one part of the question:

> **either** (might be easier to implement ?):
>
> ```
> (front of 1st paper)    (back of 1st paper)
>  ________ ________       ________ ________
> |        |        |     |        |        |
> |        |        |     |        |        |
> |        |        |     |        |        |
> |_____1__|_____3__|     |__2_____|__4_____|
> ```
>
> which should stack like that
>
> ```
>           /|=====>>/|
>      1 ->/ |  5 ->/ |
>         /  |     /  |
>        / 2 |    / 6 |
>        |\  |    |\  |
>        | \ |    | \ |  ...
>        |  \     |  \ 
>        |   |    |   |
>        | 3 |    | 7 |
>         \  |     \  |
>          \ |<- 4  \ |<- 8
>           \|=====>>\|
> ```

Usage of `pgfpmorepages` like this, creates the desired layout:

```
\documentclass[
    12pt, 
    % a4paper
    twoside
]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfmorepages} % before pdfpages !
\usepackage{pdfpages}

%
\newlength{\distup}
\setlength{\distup}{\dimexpr\voffset+1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep\relax}
\newlength{\distleft}
\setlength{\distleft}{\dimexpr1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin\relax}
\newlength{\distdown}
\setlength{\distdown}{\dimexpr\paperheight-\distup-\textheight\relax}
\newlength{\distright}
\setlength{\distright}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\distleft-\textwidth\relax}
%

\pgfmorepagesloadextralayouts

\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 2, book format}[
  a4paper,
  landscape,
  % border code=\pgfusepath{draw}
]

\begin{document}
    \includepdf[
        pages=-,
        clip,
        trim={{\distleft} {\distdown} {\distright} {\distup}},
        frame
    ]{testfile.pdf}

\end{document}
```

---

#### edit:

1. This apparently does not allow to flip every other page (or I could not figure out how; [`reverse second`](https://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfmorepages/pgfmorepages.pdf) threw a compilation error). Feel free to improve this answer or add an improved answer.
2. [`book format`](https://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfmorepages/pgfmorepages.pdf) and *short page edge binding* printing-option does the trick though!